# How to make dynamic (variable) content with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, twig

My first problem, i don't know make a dynamic template in twig with AngularJs.
The purpose of my project, then making a page editor app.
So, first of all:
- I get a JSON file in the following structure
- I started processing the content of JSON file, but I'm getting stuck in processing. 
Can I ask for a nice solution?
Many thanks!

```
/* Json file */

$scope.form={
'content': 
    [{   
        "name"  : "text_right",
        "img"   : "nope.jpg",
        "text"  : "<span>text text text</span>"           
    },
    {   
        "name"  : "text_left",
        "text"  : "<span>text text text</span>",
        "img"   : "nope.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name"  : "text_both",
        "textL"  : "<span>text text text</span>",
        "textR"  : "<span>text text text</span>"
    },
    {
        "name"  : "special",
        "text"  : "<div>text text text</div>"
    }]
};
```

```
/* HTML content */

<div class="col-12" ng-repeat="(key, value) in form.content">
    [[ initTemp(key) ]]
</div>
```

```
/* AngularJs */
$scope.initTemp = function($key){
    let html;

    if(form.content[$key].name ==  "text_both"){
        html = textBoth();
    }
    if(form.content[$key].name == "text_left"){
        html = textLeft();
    }
    return $compile(html)($scope);
}
function textBoth($key){
    return `
        <div class="col-6"><input ng-model="form.content.${$key}.textL"></div>
        <div class="col-6"><input ng-model="form.content.${$key}.textR"></div>
    `;
}
function textLeft($key){
    return `
        <div class="col-6"><input ng-model="form.content.${$key}.text"></div>
        <div class="col-6"><input ng-model="form.content.${$key}.img"></div>
    `;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that assembles DOM from data is best done in a custom directive:

```
<div class="col-12" ng-repeat="item in form.content">
     ̶[̶[̶ ̶i̶n̶i̶t̶T̶e̶m̶p̶(̶k̶e̶y̶)̶ ̶]̶]̶
     <custom-directive item="item"></custom-directive>
</div>
```

```js
app.directive("customDirective", function($compile) {
    return {
        link: postLink,
    };
    function postLink (scope,elem,attrs) {
        var item=scope.$eval(attrs.item);
        var html = `
            <div>
               <img src=${item.img} />
               <!-- ... -->
            </div>
        `;
        var linkfn = $compile(html);
        elem.append(linkfn(scope)); 
    }
})
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)